# Реакция на input по значению в словаре

Tags: python

Вопрос от новичка Python
Ничего не выводит.
Хотя пишу в `'user' -> Привет`

```
vocabulary = {
    'hello': ('Привет' , 'привет' ,)
}

user = input('Enter: ')

if user == 'hello' :
    print('Hello')
```

Comment: `if user in vocabulary['hello'] : print('Hello')`

Comment: Не хочет работать                                                                                                                                   
if user in vocabulary['hello'] :                                                                                                    
        print('Hello')                                                                                                                                                                 Всё так же просто просит ввести и конец

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
vocabulary = { 'hello': ('Привет' , 'привет' ,) }

user = input('Enter: ')

#if user == 'hello' : print('Hello')
if user in vocabulary['hello']: 
    print('Hello')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скопировал ваш код,но всё так же.Никакой ошибки нет

Comment: @Krempli что вы вводите после `Enter: ` ?

Comment: Слово 'Привет'..

Comment: @Krempli вводите без кавычек `Привет`

Comment: Я без кавычек ввожу)

Comment: Добавил в словарь слово 'hello' и снова попытался, заработало.Не работает почему только с русскими словами

Comment: @Krempli поставьте перед `if `  `print(vocabulary['hello'])` и покажите вывод.

Comment: Немного не понял, показать то что он выведет?

Answer (score 0):

```
vocabulary = {
    'привет': 'hello'
}

user = input('Enter: ')
print(vocabulary[user.lower().strip()] if user.lower().strip() in vocabulary else None)
```

Comment: Просто выводит None

Comment: @Krempli, У вас какое направление перевода должно быть? ru-en или en-ru?

Comment: ru-en          //////////////

Comment: @Krempli, переделал

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]